# Maven: passing system properties between lifecycle phases

Tags: java, maven, properties, maven-plugin, lifecycle

I am not very familiar with Maven yet, so I am struggling to get this done:

I'm using exec-maven-plugin to set some system properties during `process-test-classes` phase, via `System.setProperty()` method. And they are all set properly. But when the next phase (test phase) starts, and I am listing them again, (with `properties.list(System.out)`), they are all gone.

So my question is: is there any way not to lose them while stepping to another lifecycle phase?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm a newb with Maven too, but are you *sure* that that's how you list them?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it can be achieved that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Maven Properties Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to set up properties. The plugin can read properties from a properties file and set environment properties for you to use it elsewhere.

See [usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html) for configuring the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Put the value as a variable in the pom, and refer to the variable in all the places that need it.  `exec-maven-plugin` starts and finishes in its own context.  The next goals won't have the same context.

Comment: Placing variables in pom is not an option for me. They are loaded from files copied to test-classes/ during process-test-resources phase. Does this context You have mentioned have something in common with forking VM during test phase?

Comment: Why can't you load them from that file into the pom?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the maven-surefire-plugin for the tests (and this is what you use by default), you might be having the tests forked. Forked tests are run in a separate JVM and the JVM properties are not passed to it, unless you explicitly do so.

See [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) for more details on forking.

Furthermore, each pluging runs in it's own context (also, I believe in it's own classloader). Therefore changes you make to properties will only be visible within the plugin's scope (I believe the different `<execution/>`-s of the same plugin can share these properties, but this needs to be double-checked.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the problem too: one plugin sets System props, while upon test they are not set.

So, I've made the first plugin to set maven project properties. And made surefire plugin to read them into System properties upon test phase (use 'systemPropertyVariables' param).

Hope it helps, but I don't know the exec-maven-plugin, so maybe the trick won't pass for you.